Float to int of vector
I have vector with data type of float, mainly float32. The zero value is the baseline a.k.a. mean/center of data.
It has shape (batch_size, seq_len).
I want to reduce memory usage by converting them into int8 space during store into a file. How do I do it in NumPy?
Is this same as min-max scaling problem?

It can be transformed into:
$x'=\lfloor x \frac{\lfloor \frac{2^b - 1}{2} \rfloor}{\max\lvert x \rvert} \rfloor$
Where $b$ is the number of bit, $x$ is the original float, and $x'$ is the integer representation.
Here is for the numpy where number of bit is 8:
def ieee754_to_signedint8(x, axis=-1):
  return ((x*127)/np.max(np.abs(x), axis=axis, keepdims=True)).astype(np.int8)

Tested:

But I still have unused information which is the value of -128, performing min-max of flattened vector will resulting, but not really, I can't guarantee whether there is existing -128 occured.
np.int8(-127), np.int8(127))


Quantizing float32 to int8 loses a lot of information; if you do the obvious thing of scaling the floats to [-128,127] then you will lose far too much precision. You would also have to have some way of storing information about the reverse transformation to read it back correctly.
See https://huggingface.co/docs/optimum/en/concept_guides/quantization#quantization-to-int8 for a discussion of the issues.
If you're working in the context of an LLM or similar, then there is already going to be library support for quantizing the model properly to fp8.
Instead consider:

Just save as np.float16 to save some space and lose a little precision; very simple
Save with compression
Consider whether you can sparsify the tensor first. If you can sparsify a lot, then there are sparse representations that are more efficient. If not, then setting some near-0 values to 0  where it won't matter much can save storage when compressed.


I acknowledge about data loss information, I think my model doesn't really need high granularity. It's not LLM, it's about timeseries data, so the value is continue.

I'm still expecting NumPy answer definition. I tried tinkering it, but the baseline has changed, it was not zero in the int8 space.
